# How-to know what to require to get specific part of Rails framework functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, require

When writing non-rails ruby project I often find myself in the position that I want to use certain parts of the Rails framework. This can be object extensions (like the String method camelize) or, as today, `ActionDispatch::Assertions::SelectorAssertions`, where I just want to add `css_select` to some of my tests.

I get pretty confused often over hyphenation/underscoring and often struggle to find out, what exactly I have to require. And I haven't found a system yet...

Is there a rule as to how to require a part of Rails if I know what module or class I want?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use active support library of rails. It has huge set of inbuilt methods which you can use in your ruby code. Just write in your ruby code.

```
 require 'active_support'
```

http://as.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Hey Ashish, active_support does have a whole lot of stuff! However, on the one hand it does not have the method mentioned above (it is in actionpack) and on the other hand it bloats the project even more, which I find undesirable in certain projects.

Comment: Yes you are right...But you want to have hyphenation/underscoring related method which are available in AS.